# SVG responsive design

Tags: html, svg

MY SVG logo is  responsive, however i'm unsure why this is working, I was expecting this to be far more complicated and feel i'm missing something here

**Here is the HTML for my logo:**

-The width of the logo container is defined by bootstrap class col-xs-6

-All images are set to max-width {100%} in my css

-Header height is set to AUTO

```
<div id="logo" class="col-xs-6 clearfix">
  <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="The website logo">
</div>
```

**Here is the XML for my logo:**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 57.8 15" enable-background="new 0 0 57.8 15" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.7" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="56.8" height="13.8"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.0075 10.044)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">logo</text>
<g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#1E6E30" d="M-0.2,3.8c17.7,0.4,35.3,0.5,53,0.3c1.4,0,3.7-2.9,3.8-2.9C39,1.4,21.3,1.3,3.6,0.9
            C2.3,0.9-0.1,3.8-0.2,3.8L-0.2,3.8z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

**My questions**

Do i need to add some delete any XML? and should I use the CSS below?
It looks like  the SVG is working like any other image, should I make any adjustments?

```
#logo img 
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;   
}
```

Many thanks for your time

Comment: SVG with a viewBox and percentage width/height is generally responsive. Yours have those, so they are. That's basically all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks Robert. If I drew a rectangle (as my logo) and removed the width height properties from the XML, then I define   logo img width 100% and height 100% in my CSS, would that be Ok? I assume the logo would just fill the containing logo DIV?

Comment: You haven't got width/height in your SVG, you're relying on the defaults of 100% which is fine for a standalone document. You won't be able to override this with CSS unless you put the CSS inline in the SVG file itself and anyway you don't need to.

Comment: Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ – that explains scaling of SVG images pretty exhaustively.

Answer (score -2):

Since their is no width/height parameter in your svg container, hence it doesn't know about those params for fixed width/height.Try this

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="480" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 57.8 15" enable-background="new 0 0 57.8 15" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.7" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="56.8" height="13.8"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.0075 10.044)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="12">logo</text>
<g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#1E6E30" d="M-0.2,3.8c17.7,0.4,35.3,0.5,53,0.3c1.4,0,3.7-2.9,3.8-2.9C39,1.4,21.3,1.3,3.6,0.9
            C2.3,0.9-0.1,3.8-0.2,3.8L-0.2,3.8z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I simply added width/height params to your svg.